# Why is (L \ 12) calculating to 0?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to do calculations through VBA.

I am doing it through the form itself because when Production creates one of these Job Tickets a number of fields can change on the fly. Which Unit of Measure we are running in, which type of Wood, how we Wrap it, etc.

All of these changes affect the total footage or amount of pieces we have to run, which is why I have If-Then-Else statements for them.

It works until I get to Wrap SQ Footage. I get a zero inserted into my field, but when I do the calculations on my own I never get 0.

I created this expression in the control source of one of the Wrap SQ Footages, and it comes out correctly.

```
=Abs(Int( (([Wrap_Slit1]/12) * [Quantity_Ordered] ) * ( [RIP_Scrap_Rate] + 1))))
```

```vb
Private Sub FTG_Calculations()

    'Declare Variable
    Dim L As Double
    Dim Length As Double
    Dim OrderFTG As Double
    Dim UoM As String
    Dim W As Double
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Set frm = Forms!Frm_JobTicket
    
    'Set L equal to Length from Tbl_JobTicketMould
    L = DLookup("Length", "Tbl_JobTicketMould", "Access_ID =" & Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Part_Number)
    
    'Convert Length to Feet
    Length = (L \ 12)
    
    'Find Unit of Measure for this part
    UoM = DLookup("Unit_of_Measure", "Tbl_JobTicketUoM", "Access_ID =" & Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Part_Number)
    
    'Mupltiply Length times Quantity to get Order Footage
    OrderFTG = Int((Length * Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket))
    
    'If UoM is PCS then insert that number. Otherwise set equal to Quantity Ordered divided by Length of piece(in FT)
    If UoM = "PCS" Then Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket = Me.Quantity_Ordered Else: Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket = Abs(Int(Me.Quantity_Ordered \ Length))
    
    'Define limits of the loop. Then runs through all Wrap SQ FTG fields and inputs calculation
    For W = 1 To 3
    
       'If UoM is PCS then calculate Order Footage to find Wrap Sqaure Footage. Otherwise take slit size in FT and multiply by Order Quantity and Scrap Rate
        If UoM = "PCS" Then
            frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * OrderFTG) * (Round((frm("RIP_Scrap_Rate")), 3) + 1))
        Else: frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * frm(Quantity_Ordered)) * (frm(RIP_Scrap_Rate + 1)))
        End If
    Next W
```

I figured out the issue is in the `(frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12)` area. Wrap_Slit1 shows a value of 2 in the data tips, but when I divide by 12 it comes out to 0.

All of my data points are set to double, and the variables are declared as double. It is rounding down when it should come out to .16667.

Comment: Debug line for line while studying the values of the controls.

Comment: I have tried that, but to no avail. That's not very surprising though - I am next to lost when it comes to debugging. I can't even get the data tips to show up all of the time.

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: One-liners like `If foo Then bar Else: stuff` hurt readability and debugging. Separate lines are better for that.

Comment: _I am next to lost when it comes to debugging._ Then start now. Good link from @Andre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code before the:

```
 If UoM = "PCS" Then
```

Msgbox code:

```
MsgBox("Current State:" & vbCrLf & _
       "UoM:" & vbTab & UoM & vbCrlf & _
       "OrderFTGL" & vbTab & OrderFTG & _
       "Wrap_Slit1:" & vbTab & Me.Wrap_Slit1 & _
       ... continue pattern for other desired values in calculation...
       "Continue...", vbOK)
```

Comment: This has helped me determine that it is doing all of the calculations correctly, up until it goes to insert that calculation into my form control. All that it is inputting is 0 into the field, which seems odd because there is no 0 or null value anywhere near the ticket or for the queries that feed it.

Comment: Try dividing by 12.0 vs 12, this should force the result to be a double vs integer. Or use !12 for a single or #12 for a double.

Comment: I tried both versions, it is coming out to 0 everytime though. That is weird since the field Wrap_Slit is set to double, and has a validation rule of between 0 and 12. I have tried it with every whole number between 1 and 12 and continue to get 0. I wrote an expression to put in the field that works, but I wanted to be able to do this programmatically. The expression I wrote is above my code, but I don't see at all how that is different that what I am doing through VBA (or how 2/12 = 0 but also 6/12 = 0)

Comment: Boy am I getting old!  VBA division is forward slash / not back slash \.

Comment: That was exactly it, I changed backslashes to forward slashes and voila! I cannot believe that is the mistake I made. I had read somewhere else on here that dividing through VBA was done through backslashes, well that teaches me for believing everything I read on the internet. You'd think growing up with it I'd have a better grasp on concepts like that lol. Thank you very much, you have saved me hours of frustrated hair pulling!

Comment: Glad to help only sorry I didn't see it earlier.